# Why Bash doesn’t pass the errexit option to command substitutions?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Shell options set by [`set` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) are inherited in sub-shells (at least the `errexit`). This can be proved by:

```bsh
set -o errexit

function foo() {
    echo "foo:$BASHPID"
    false
    echo 'after' 
}

echo "main:$BASHPID"
( foo )
```

However, the options don’t seem inherited in [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), which should also be subshells according to Bash documentation. Proof:

```bsh
set -o errexit

function foo() {
    echo "foo:$BASHPID"
    false
    echo 'after' 
}

echo "main:$BASHPID"
output=$(foo)
echo "output: $output"
```

Expected output:

```
main:123
output: foo:124
```

Actual output:

```
main:123
output: foo:124
after
```

Is that expected or a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is expected, when not in POSIX mode (like when running as `sh`), bash resets `errexit` inside command substitutions by default.

If you want `errexit` to be preserved inside command substitutions, with bash 4.4 or newer, use:

> `inherit_errexit`
>
> If set, command substitution inherits the value of the `errexit` option, instead of unsetting it in the subshell environment. This option is enabled when POSIX mode is enabled.

(From [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#:%7E:text=inherit_errexit).) [Another part from the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html#:%7E:text=when%20the%20inherit_errexit%20option%20is%20not%20enabled%2C%20bash%20clears%20the%20-e%20option%20in%20such%20subshells.) made it more explicit:

> Enabling POSIX mode has the effect of setting the `inherit_errexit` option, so subshells spawned to execute command substitutions inherit the value of the `-e` option from the parent shell. *When the `inherit_errexit` option is not enabled, Bash clears the `-e` option in such subshells.*

To verify:

```
$ bash -o errexit -c 'echo "$(echo "$SHELLOPTS")"'
braceexpand:hashall:interactive-comments
$ bash -o errexit -O inherit_errexit -c 'echo "$(echo "$SHELLOPTS")"'
braceexpand:errexit:hashall:interactive-comments
```

In bash 4.2 and older, `errexit` was displayed in the former, but still effectively disabled:

```
$ bash-4.2 -o errexit c 'echo "$(false; echo "$SHELLOPTS")"'
braceexpand:errexit:hashall:interactive-comments
$ bash-4.2 -o posix -o errexit -c 'echo "<$(false; echo "$SHELLOPTS")> $?"'
<> 1
```

Comment: Does Bash reset `errexit` on all subshells? Because my first example shows that it doesn’t when the subshell is started with `(...)` syntax. Why would that be different?

Comment: @FranklinYu no, Bash resets `errexit` on command-substitution subshells (i.e. those created by `$()`). It does not reset `errext` on normal subshells (and also does not reset on process-substitution subshells (i.e. those created by `<()`).